# what is ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com? google keeps sending me to it when I search for Mathematica questions

Tags: discussion

To find something in MSE (Mathematica stackexchange), I normally use google. Recently, I keep getting top hits all from site `ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com` It seems like a duplicate of MSE.  Here is an example of a question I was searching for and this came first (before even our own MSE)

https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/mathematica/A/question/152559.html

It seems safe and my anti-virus did not complain about anything.

Is the above domain related to our own site in any way? Strange it shows up before showing anything from [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions) so I thought to ask.

Answer (score 8):

This is related to a demonstration project that Cloudflare undertook when they introduced their InterPlanetary File System Gateway.  Quoting from the blog post [Cloudflare goes InterPlanetary - Introducing Cloudflare’s IPFS Gateway](https://blog.cloudflare.com/distributed-web-gateway/):

> **What can you do with Cloudflare’s Gateway?**
>
> *[...]*
>
> A fun example we’ve put together using the [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/) archives of all
>   the different StackExchange websites and build a distributed search
>   engine on top of that using only IPFS. Check it out [here](https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/).

The post is silent about whether this was done with the consent of StackExchange.  But Cloudflare and Kiwix have reputations to protect so I imagine that the use is legitimate (although if it is not, deleting content from [IPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System) could be challenging).

As to why a Google search now ranks this site so highly, it must be some sort of interaction between the search terms, your user profile on Google and the [<strike>25 Billion</strike> Trillion Dollar Eigenvector Problem](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf) :)